# Validating the base I found diagonalizes a linear operator.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

The exercise is quite simple, I did not have too much trouble solving, yet I'm having an issue validating my results, mainly due to a gap in how I was taught the subject.

The exercise is such:

For the following linear operator, determine weather it is diagonalizable or not, if it is, find the diagonalizing base.

$$
T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R^3}
$$
$$
T\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4a-2b+4c\\b+3c\\b-c\end{pmatrix}
$$

I found the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectores.

Afterwards I've placed the eigenvectors I found (3 of them, all have algebraic multiplicity equal to their geometric multiplicity) in a group $B$.

After constructing $[T]_B$ using the eigenvectors I've placed in $B$, I've got that:
$[T]_B$  is a 3x3 matrix, yet not a diagonal one.

Only after performing elementary row operations on $[T]_B$ I've got it to a diagonal form.

My question here is such:

Does this mean the group B I've constructed is a diagonalizing base?

If not, does that mean that a group $S$ is a diagonalizing base only when $[T]_S$ is in diagonal form straight off the bat?

Any information/answers are appriciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you make row operations? After all, any invertible matrix can be brought to a diagonal form by row operations. If $B$ is a diagonalizing basis then $[T]_B$ itself is a diagonal matrix. It is a basic theorem that a basis $B$ is a diagonalizing basis if and only if all the elements of $B$ are eigenvectors of $T$.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix of the linear operator $T$ is:

$A = [T] = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
       4 & -2 & 4 \\
        0 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{array} \right] $.

It is easy to verify that $A$ has 3 distinct eigenvalues

$ 4, 2, -2$

and the corresponding independent eigenvectors are:

$
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{array} \right], \ 
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 3 \\ 1 \\ \end{array} \right],
\
\left[ \begin{array}{c} -1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ \end{array} \right].
$

These eigenvectors are the basis vectors you are looking for.

Good luck!

Comment: Indeed those are the eigenvectors I've got to, yet when I calculate $[T]_B$, the matrix I receive is not diagonal. is that okay?